# How to convert a string to a byte array which is compiled with a given charset in Go?

Tags: string, character-encoding, go, byte-shifting

In java, we can use the method of String : byte[] getBytes(Charset charset) .
This method Encodes a String into a sequence of bytes using the given charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

But how to do this in GO?
Is there any similar way in Go can do this?

Please let me know it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard Go library only supports Unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) and ASCII encoding. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

The [go-charset](http://code.google.com/p/go-charset/) package (found from [here](http://godashboard.appspot.com/)) supports conversion to and from UTF-8 and it also links to the GNU iconv library.

See also field `CharsetReader` in [encoding/xml.Decoder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder).

Comment: I don't think Go natively supports UTF-16 or 32 only UTF-8 and ASCII. Any other charset will have to be treated as a slice of bytes and use a package such as go-charset to be properly handled.

Comment: The type `rune` is UTF-32. UTF-16 is package `unicode/utf16`.

Comment: The type rune is a unicode code point it's just a int32 number this means that a slice of []rune is essentially an slice of utf-32 characters. and you it supports native conversion between the two so I suppose you can make the case that utf-8 and utf32 are supported natively.

Answer (score 1):

I believe here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6933412/1315563

> There is no way to do it without writing the conversion yourself or
>   using a third-party package. You could try using this:
>   http://code.google.com/p/go-charset