# Reading a non UTF-8 text file in Go

Tags: character-encoding, go

I need to read a text file that is encoded in [GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK). The standard library in Go programming language assumes that all text is encoded in UTF-8.

How can I read files in other encodings?

Comment: This looks like a very reasonable and clear question, voting to re-open (even in its original form)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Previously (as mentioned in an older answer) the "easy" way to do this involved using third party packages that needed cgo and wrapped the iconv library. That is undesirable for many reasons. Thankfully, for quite a while now there has been a superior all Go way of doing this using only packages provided by the Go Authors (not in the main set of packages but in the [Go Sub-Repositories](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SubRepositories)).

The [`golang.org/x/text/encoding`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding) package defines an interface for generic character encodings that can convert to/from UTF-8. The [`golang.org/x/text/encoding/simplifiedchinese`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/simplifiedchinese) sub-package provides [GB18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB18030), [GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) and [HZ-GB2312](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB2312#HZ) encoding implementations.

Here is an example of reading and writing a GBK encoded file. Note that the `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` do the encoding "on the fly" as data is being read/written.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/simplifiedchinese"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
)

// Encoding to use. Since this implements the encoding.Encoding
// interface from golang.org/x/text/encoding you can trivially
// change this out for any of the other implemented encoders,
// e.g. `traditionalchinese.Big5`, `charmap.Windows1252`,
// `korean.EUCKR`, etc.
var enc = simplifiedchinese.GBK

func main() {
    const filename = "example_GBK_file"
    exampleWriteGBK(filename)
    exampleReadGBK(filename)
}

func exampleReadGBK(filename string) {
    // Read UTF-8 from a GBK encoded file.
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r := transform.NewReader(f, enc.NewDecoder())

    // Read converted UTF-8 from `r` as needed.
    // As an example we'll read line-by-line showing what was read:
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for sc.Scan() {
        fmt.Printf("Read line: %s\n", sc.Bytes())
    }
    if err = sc.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = f.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func exampleWriteGBK(filename string) {
    // Write UTF-8 to a GBK encoded file.
    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    w := transform.NewWriter(f, enc.NewEncoder())

    // Write UTF-8 to `w` as desired.
    // As an example we'll write some text from the Wikipedia
    // GBK page that includes Chinese.
    _, err = fmt.Fprintln(w,
        `In 1995, China National Information Technology Standardization
Technical Committee set down the Chinese Internal Code Specification
(Chinese: 汉字内码扩展规范（GBK）; pinyin: Hànzì Nèimǎ
Kuòzhǎn Guīfàn (GBK)), Version 1.0, known as GBK 1.0, which is a
slight extension of Codepage 936. The newly added 95 characters were not
found in GB 13000.1-1993, and were provisionally assigned Unicode PUA
code points.`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = f.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/fEBzqxKrd6Z)

Answer (score 5):

Try [go-iconv](https://github.com/djimenez/iconv-go). It wraps `iconv` and implements `io.Reader` and `io.Writer`.

This [message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-china/QRR-pepLWYI) in golang-china discussion group is mentioning a few examples of `go-iconv` usage.

Comment: Another option would be to read the file as an opaque blob into a buffer and then interpret it as being text in a particular encoding using [go-charset](http://code.google.com/p/go-charset); see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10039701/720999) for more info.  I did not look at the code, but it appears that to support a set of most used legacy charsets/encodings, this package does not need iconv which might be an advantage.

Comment: @kostix From information on the title page of http://code.google.com/p/go-charset it seems that in case of gbk the package uses GNU iconv library.

Comment: This package can also be used to perform the transformation: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding