# XML parsing not happening with Prolog

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

Recently I starting using Go. I am facing one problem while parsing XML.

Here is the issue:

I am successfully able to parse the following XML:

```
<Root>
<cookie name="e1">hsdhsdhs</cookie>
<cookie name="e2">sssss</cookie>
<cookie name="e3">null</cookie>
<info>
<name>sam</name>
</info>
</Root>
```

Here are the structs:

```
type Profile struct {
    RootElement xml.Name    `xml:"Root"`
    CookieList  []Cookie    `xml:"cookie"`
    Info        Information `xml:"info"`
}

type Cookie struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Information struct {
    Name       string `xml:"name"`
}
```

And the above struct is working fine.

```
profile := Profile{}
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlString), &profile)
jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(profile)
fmt.Println(string(jsonData))
```

But as I keep prolog in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="EUC-JP"?>
    <Root>
    <cookie name="e1">hsdhsdhs</cookie>
    <cookie name="e2">sssss</cookie>
    <cookie name="e3">null</cookie>
    <info>
    <name>sam</name>
    </info>
    </Root>
```

then while printing, no data is displaying inside the JSON.

Not sure what is the issue here with Prolog.

Comment: Change the encoding to utf-8..??

Comment: Yes. Then it's working. But I need it for EUC-JP.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with parsing using EUC-JP

Comment: @nagendra547 Can you add `Information` struct too?

Comment: If you want to use non-utf8, you might want to use Go Sub-Repositories. Here is an  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277933/reading-a-non-utf-8-text-file-in-go

Comment: http://blog.tristanmedia.com/2014/10/using-go-to-parse-non-utf8-xml-feeds/

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Added information Struct

Answer (score 2):

Before parsing non-utf8 xml document you have to difine charset reader, thanks to `golang.org/x/net/html/charset` all you need to do is just replace this string:

```
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlString), &profile)
```

with:

```
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(xmlString))
decoder.CharsetReader = charset.NewReaderLabel
err := decoder.Decode(&profile)
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, but one issue I found, if there are some Japanese characters in name(e.g - サム   ) under Information, then it's printing in weird fashion. It's printing binary characters I guess.

Comment: @nagendra547 I just tested these symbols in xml and it outputs fine in json. By name you mean `name` attribute of the `cookie` tag?

Comment: name under the info TAG